# Simple way to add a Premake subproject inside a CMake project?

Tags: cmake, premake

I use **CMake** for my C++ projects and I like to have my dependencies as **Git submodules** inside a *third-party* folder so I can have easy access to the code and the possible CMake targets I can link with.

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   └── main.cpp
└── third-party
    └── CMakeSubmodule        # OK
        └── CMakeLists.txt    # OK
```

My root CMakeLists.txt would typically contain :

```
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(third-party/CMakeSubmodule)
target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE SubmoduleTarget)
```

---

Now, I want to add a submodule that only uses **premake** :

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   └── main.cpp
└── third-party
    └── PremakeSubmodule    # !
        └── premake5.lua    # !
```

***How would you do to simply add the submodule as a dependency ?***

Do I have to manually convert all premake files to CMakeLists.txt ?

---

A convenient solution would allow to directly link to a target as follow, so I don't have to manually set the correct include directories and link to the lib files :

```
target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE PremakeTarget)   # Would be great
```

Comment: Any non-CMake project can be built in CMake via [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html). After that, you may create IMPORTED or INTERFACE target, which properties corresponds to actual library file(s) and include directories of that external project. So you may use this target as `target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE PremakeTarget)`.